# Exporting member function of a static library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, static-libraries, member-functions

Is it possible (or relevant at all) to export member functions of a static library?
When I "dumpbin /EXPORTS" my .lib file I don't see any of my defined class members.

- Linking to this lib file succeeds, but I use an external tool that fails to read non-exported symbols.
- Also tried adding a .def file with no results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A static library is just a collection of .o files. This is then linked into your executable in exactly the same way as .o files so whatever works for .o files will work for static libraries.